# How can I create a batch script which selects the oldest file in a folder, renames it, moves it to another file and renames it again?

Tags: file, batch-file, rename, move

I am very new to programming/coding.
I'll try my best to explain my problem (sry for my english).

Im working on a Windows Server 2012 and I want to create a batch script which selects the oldest file in a folder, renames it, moves it to another folder and renames it again.

Another way to explain it:

- I have a folder with 15 files in it
- The oldest file is called "orange"
- I want the script to rename the "orange" file
- Now moving the file to another folder and finally rename it again

I got this so far from somewhere else in here but I dont know if it works or what exactly it means I just saved it so I have at least something to show you guys..

```
@echo off
cd c:\Test
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W') do (
    move "%%a" C:\Another\Location
    goto continue
)

:continue
```

I think I have to include the following:  ren [drive:][path]TargetMask but Im not sure at all... 
I hope you can understand this. I already tried to look up my problem but just got more confused... Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How about you try it, and see if it works? if it does you could always move it back, of you're not satisfied with the result.

Comment: I see no attempt at renaming the file. You got all of the hard part of the code written. The rename is the easiest.

Comment: rename it to what?

Comment: So... how about this one? Sry guys like I told you before Im an absolute beginner.. I dont even know how to test the code.... or how to transfer a text document into a bat file. I tried to rename the document to .bat in the end but it didnt work. 

@echo off

cd c:\Test

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W') do (

   ren [drive:][path]TargetMask

   move "%%a" C:\Another\Location

   ren [drive:][path]TargetMask

   goto continue

)

:continue

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to move and rename the oldest (by last written time) file in a folder using cmd, pushd, for in do, set, move, and popd.

When you are happy the script will do what it says it will do make the following changes.

Change `%userprofile%\desktop` to `C:\Another\Location`

Change `pushd "%userprofile%\desktop"` to `pushd c:\test`

Change `echo move` to `move`

[Rob Vanderwoude NT FOR](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php)

script:

```
@rem How to move and rename the oldest (by last written time) file in a folder using cmd, pushd, for in do, set, move, and popd.
@rem Windows 10 64-bit
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
pushd "%userprofile%\desktop"
FOR /f "delims=" %%g IN ('DIR /b /a-d /o-d /tw') DO (
SET zold=%%g  
SET zoldname=%%~ng
)
echo move /y %zold% %userprofile%\desktop\%zoldname%.bat
popd 
exit /b
```

cmd:

```
cmd /eq
pushd "%userprofile%\desktop"
FOR /f "delims=" %g IN ('DIR /b /a-d /o-d /tw') DO (
SET zold=%g  
SET zoldname=%~ng
)
echo move /y %zold% %userprofile%\desktop\%zoldname%.bat
popd 
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks @somebadhat Can you please help me understand the command file syntax